# What do the updates do?

Tags: updates, xubuntu

I am using Xubuntu. What do the updates do? I do not notice any difference after an update. The descriptions do not really them me and they benefit me. A way to find out what each update does is as good as an answer, since I assume that the updates do not all do the same thing.

--Update--
Also, what is the best way to figure what each update does (like a meaningful summary of each individually.) Just edit the already accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- They are bug fixes for installed apps
- Security fixes for OS
- Hardware fixes
- Unity/Gnome/KDE/Xfce Fixes and updates
- Also new features in some cases (Thanks Ashu)

They are helping you just you wont see the benefit of them all. I update regularly to make sure I have the latest security fixes. You don't need to update all the time, if you have a stable install just work with it until you feel you want to upgrade.

Bill

Comment: Actually, I always update. I just wanted to know what they did.

Comment: Yeh totally so do I. But if you do a sudo apt-get update its just checking to see if there are any updates for each of your apps or OS bug fixes etc. That's about it I would think.

Comment: +1 @WilliamFleming they also provide new features . add that.

Comment: I do know and occasionally use apt-get updates and upgrade, but I mostly use the graphical interface (it checks for you.)